# ASP.NET MVC List All Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to show a list of all users but am unsure how to go about this using the MVC model.

I can obtain the list of all users via the `Membership.GetAllUsers()` method however if I try to pass this to the view from the `ActionResult`, I'm told that Model is not enumerable.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I'm new to this MVC stuff and didn't realise I could strongly type the Model. Cheers !!

Comment: With ASP.NET MVC 4 and the SimpleMembershipProvider `Membership.GetAllUsers()` is not supported.  Instead use, `using (var ctx = new UsersContext()) { var users = ctx.UserProfiles.ToList(); }`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to set the View to accept an object of type MembershipUserCollection

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MembershipUserCollection>" %>
```

In your action:

```
 public ActionResult GetUsers()
        {
            var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
            return View(users);
        }
```

then you can write in your view something like:

```
 <ul>
       <%foreach (MembershipUser user in Model){ %>

       <li><%=user.UserName %></li>

       <% }%>
</ul>
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working in MVC4 in my application

Answer (score 3):

In your view page, on top, you need to set the type of the view page. IE:

On the top of your View, in the first line of the markup, you'll see something like this:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"
```

Change that to be:

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MembershipUserCollection>"
```

or whatever the type you're trying to pass to the view. The "Model" object will now be of type MembershipUserCollection which you can safely iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] Specifically, what does the view look like (e.g. what's it expecting to get as the model, how are you parsing the collection, etc.)

Can you post some code?  I'm doing something similar, but am having no problems.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to make your view strongly typed view.  Have your view derive from `ViewPage<MembershipUserCollection>`  instead of just `ViewPage`.  Another solution is to cast your Model to MembershipUserCollection in your view:

```
<% var members = (MembershipUserCollection) ViewData.Model %>
<% foreach (MembershipUser user in members) { %>
       <%-- Do Stuff with the user --%>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try asp.net application object

```
        string id = Session.SessionID.ToString();
        String[] users = new String[1000];
        users = (string[])Application["users"];
        int count=0;
        for (int d=0;1000 >d ;d++ )
        {
            if (users == null) { users = new String[1000]; }
            count = d;
            if (users[d] == null) { break; }
        }
        users[count] = id;
        Application["users"] = users;
        string[] usersTable = (string[])Application["users"];
        for (int d=0;1000 >d ;d++ )
        {
            if (usersTable[d] == null) { break; }
        Label1.Text += usersTable[d].ToString()+" | ";
```

add to application object code

```
        Application["users"] = users;
```

retrive from applicaton object

```
        string[] usersTable = (string[])Application["users"];
```

this will help you